# Change style of one particular list item by hovering it - CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list like this and I want it to change the font-weight to bold of the list item which I was hovering but instead of that it applies the changes for the whole list of all lists of my document (depends on my attempts)

```css
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="2.css">
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>Animals
      <ul>
        <li>Mammals
          <ul>
            <li>Cows</li>
            <li>Donkeys</li>
            <li>Dogs</li>
            <li>Tigers</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Other
          <ul>
            <li>Snakes</li>
            <li>Birds</li>
            <li>Lizards</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fishes
      <ul>
        <li>Aquarium
          <ul>
            <li>Guppy</li>
            <li>Angelfish</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Sea
          <ul>
            <li>Sea trout</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to know is there a way to do it without adding IDs or classes to the elements.

And I want it to do in a dynamic way.

If there's a way to do it with JS it will be great too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change opacity on all elements except hovered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26527443/change-opacity-on-all-elements-except-hovered-one)

Comment: @Vepthy No, it's not.

Comment: What about this option here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/13233878/11799851

Comment: @cluelessdev sorry but not. I don't have nested tags.

Comment: With the structure you have , it's not possible with CSS only... Yes it's possible with js without id and class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach that seems to work. To explain:

- `li` elements are explicitly given a `font-weight: normal` so that `font-weight: bold` on parents doesn't cascade.
- A `mouseover` event handler is placed on the top level to handle all descendent events. The `true` `useCapture` parameter for `addEventListener` allows us to do this.
- We allow the event to continue bubbling until we hit an `li` target.
- We then programmatically set the `font-weight` for the `li`
- By preventing further propagation, we make sure that *parent* `li` elements aren't notified when a descendent has already been bolded

```js
const tree = document.getElementById('tree');
tree.addEventListener('mouseover', (event) => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    event.target.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}, true);
tree.addEventListener('mouseout', (event) => {
  if (event.target.tagName === 'LI') {
    event.target.style.removeProperty('font-weight');
  }
}, true);
```

```css
#tree li {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="2.css">
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>Animals
      <ul>
        <li>Mammals
          <ul>
            <li>Cows</li>
            <li>Donkeys</li>
            <li>Dogs</li>
            <li>Tigers</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Other
          <ul>
            <li>Snakes</li>
            <li>Birds</li>
            <li>Lizards</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fishes
      <ul>
        <li>Aquarium
          <ul>
            <li>Guppy</li>
            <li>Angelfish</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Sea
          <ul>
            <li>Sea trout</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following @Armin Guearmazi's answer, this should kinda work:

```css
ul li ul li ul li:hover,
ul li ul li:hover,
ul li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}


ul li ul li:hover ul,
ul li:hover li,
ul li:hover ul {
  cursor: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="2.css">
</head>
<body>

  <ul class="tree" id="tree">
    <li>Animals
      <ul>
        <li>Mammals
          <ul>
            <li>Cows</li>
            <li>Donkeys</li>
            <li>Dogs</li>
            <li>Tigers</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Other
          <ul>
            <li>Snakes</li>
            <li>Birds</li>
            <li>Lizards</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Fishes
      <ul>
        <li>Aquarium
          <ul>
            <li>Guppy</li>
            <li>Angelfish</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Sea
          <ul>
            <li>Sea trout</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I want it to change style only the exact element that is hovered. And it doesn't look like a dynamic way :/

Comment: What do you mean with "a dynamic way"?

Comment: I mean if I will add or remove some elements (in-depth) it will not broke the code.

Comment: Then you cannot do that with CSS. You will need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Rest all is fine, just try this CSS code:

```
ul li ul li ul li:hover {
    /* Here write your styling code */
}
```

I hope that this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [css element selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_element.asp) to select some tags contained in another one. Its syntax is very simple:

```
ul li ul li ul li:hover {
   /*Your style here*/
}
```

See a [demo](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_element_element)

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for the parent list items + I want it to be a dynamic way

Comment: Then add one to parent list item: `ul li ul li:hover` and `ul li:hover`

Comment: @Vepthy how exactly? Can you show it on the working example, please?

Comment: Yeah sure. Second

Answer (score 0):

```
ul li ul li ul li:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            font-weight: bold;
        }
```

Replace your styling with this and you'll be good to go.